# Does roscpy has any meaning?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I came across a package namely robot_arm_ros. And in the subpackage robot_arm_navigation i found this:

```
<build_exec>roscpy<build_exec>
```

I thought roscpy at first was only a typo( for rospy) but it was written 2 times. So i wonder if there was really a roscpy that was deprecated long ago. And does rospy interpret the script or compile it into executables (that might explain the name roscpy) ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340257/does-roscpy-has-any-meaning?/) by [thangvip5432](https://answers.ros.org/users/47824/thangvip5432/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, this is most likely a typo.

The two client libraries would be `roscpp` and `rospy`.

> And does rospy interpret the script or compile it into executables (that might explain the name roscpy) ?

The Python *interpreter* interprets Python code. It does not turn them into executables (in the traditional sense of the word, ie: executable binaries).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-18**:
See also #q156696 for an earlier question that mentions `roscpy`.